# Python ssh paramiko to detect failed command

Tags: python, linux, shell, ssh, paramiko

I am using paramiko to establish ssh session and send commands to the server.

Few of the commands are not successfully executed. How do i detect those commands are failed to execute and terminate python code.
Below is the code what I am trying :

```
remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
     paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(host, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
print "SSH connection established to %s" % host
# Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
remote_conn.send("\n")
remote_conn.send("scope org engg\n")
remote_conn.send("\n")
remote_conn.send("show service-profile")
if remote_conn.recv_ready():
   details = remote_conn.recv(5000)
remote_conn.close()
```

Details output:

```
  servera# scope org engg 
  Error: Managed object does not exist # org engg is not exist that the reason we are getting this error
  servera#
  servera# show service-profile

  % Incomplete Command at '^' marker # since the above command is failed but paramiko does not able to identify it is moving to second command execution . There is no org engg so that the reason i am getting incomplete command warning.
```

Note: This is not a shell so I have to use shell invoke here.

Please help how to detect not successful ran command and terminate the python program.

Comment: paramiko cannot tell you if the command failed or not. you have to parse the output all by yourself.

Comment: Thanks i will do same way

Answer (score -1):

One way to do that is:

- create a small bash script locally which can handle errors,
- copy the script in the remote server using `scp`,
- run the script and catch it's output,
- parse the output to see if an error occurs.

Here is an example of bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function error() {
    local parent_line_no="$1"
    local message="$2"
    local code="${3:-1}"
    if [[ -n "$message" ]] ; then
        echo "Error on or near line ${parent_line_no}: ${message}; exiting with status ${code}"
    else
        echo "Error on or near line ${parent_line_no}; exiting with status ${code}"
    fi
    exit "${code}"
}
trap 'error ${LINENO}' ERR

# your commands here...
```

Comment: remote server is not unix/linux based server this will work?

Comment: @asteroid4u: Yes, this is a **bash** script.

Comment: the OP's remote login shell does not look like bash.

Comment: yes remote server does not bash shell its kind of of switch